# Is List Comprehension the Right Way to Merge these JSON files Python?

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

How can I use python list comprehension to replace values in one JSON file with linked values in a separate JSON file?

One will look like this and have an "a" value I need to use to replace a value in the other list, using "b" as the connector (a, b and c values are all unique ids):

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "a": "7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd",
         "b":"b8",
      },
      {
         "a": "9ty562349u23lesdfsfd",
         "b":"b6",
      },
      {
         "a": "Ur233Fglesdfsfd",
         "b":"b2",
      }
   ]
}
```

the other will look like this where the "d"s need to be replaced with the corresponding "a" values where "b" is the key:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "c":00023414,
         "d":["b8","b6"]
      },
      {
         "c":0005814,
         "d":["b8","b2","b6"]
      }
   ]
}
```

So I end up with:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "c":00023414,
         "d":["7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd","9ty562349u23lesdfsfd"]
      },
      {
         "c":0005814,
         "d":["7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd","Ur233Fglesdfsfd","9ty562349u23lesdfsfd"]
      }
   ]
}
```

What's the right way to approach this using python, especially if I need code to be performant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files aren't valid JSON. You should check with a JSON validator like [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/)

```
In [494]: import json

In [495]: with open('/Users/ado/Desktop/ab.json') as f:
     ...:     ab = json.load(f)
     ...:

In [496]: with open('/Users/ado/Desktop/cd.json') as f:
     ...:     cd = json.load(f)
     ...:
```

Notice that you could look at `ab` simply as a collection of related `a`s and `b`s. This is a great time to use a dictionary mapping the `b`s to `a`s

```
In [497]: d_ab = {r['b']: r['a'] for r in ab['records']}

In [498]: d_ab
Out[498]:
{'b2': 'Ur233Fglesdfsfd',
 'b6': '9ty562349u23lesdfsfd',
 'b8': '7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd'}
```

Now you can iterate over the `records` in `cd` and use a `list` comprehension to create the new values

```
In [499]: for r in cd['records']:
     ...:     r['d'] = [d_ab.get(d) for d in r['d']]
     ...:

In [500]: cd
Out[500]:
{'records': [{'c': 23414,
   'd': ['7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd', '9ty562349u23lesdfsfd']},
  {'c': 5814,
   'd': ['7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd', 'Ur233Fglesdfsfd', '9ty562349u23lesdfsfd']}]}
```

Finally, write the new contents to file

```
In [502]: with open('/Users/ado/Desktop/cd-mapped.json', 'w') as f:
     ...:     f.write(json.dumps(cd))
     ...:
```

This solution presupposes that in `ab` there is always `a`s and `b`s in every record.

PS for funsies, you could use `map` and `dict.get` instead of the comprehension

```
In [505]: for r in cd['records']:
     ...:     r['d'] = list(map(d_ab.get, r['d']))
     ...:

In [506]: cd
Out[506]:
{'records': [{'c': 23414,
   'd': ['7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd', '9ty562349u23lesdfsfd']},
  {'c': 5814,
   'd': ['7hk2k989u23lesdfsfd', 'Ur233Fglesdfsfd', '9ty562349u23lesdfsfd']}]}
```

As far as performance goes, comprehensions often edge out `map`s

```
In [509]: %timeit for r in cd['records']: r['d'] = [d_ab.get(d) for d in r['d']]
     ...:
The slowest run took 7.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop

In [511]: %timeit for r in cd['records']: r['d'] = list(map(d_ab.get, r['d']))
The slowest run took 7.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 µs per loop
```

Comment: Wow, that's a really helpful insight aydow, turning a and b into key:value! Lot's to learn from in your examples.

Comment: list comprehension is an amazing feature of python

Comment: thanks @Conando :) if the answer helped you please consider upvoting and accepting